# Fails reading Google Bookmarks RSS using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, rss, bookmarks

Hi I am experiencing weird problem.
I want to consume Google Bookmarks RSS in my .NET application.
Here is the code:

```
string rssUrl = "https://www.google.com/bookmarks/?output=rss";
NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername", "mypassword");
XmlUrlResolver resolver = new XmlUrlResolver { Credentials = credentials };
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings { XmlResolver = resolver };
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(rssUrl, settings);
XDocument document1 = XDocument.Load(reader); // Fails here
```

When I open rssUrl in browser I see all my bookmarks as RSS feed prefectly.
When I run this code, it fails.
In fact, what is returned back is the Google SignOn page instead of the RSS.

**Using exactly the same code I can read Gmail RSS no problem.**

But not Google Bookmarks RSS. This doesn't make any sense to me.
It should be straight forward and very simple.

Please advice. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Do you get an error back from the server? And check your network traffic with Fiddler so you can see what you are sending over the net and what they return.

Comment: As I mentioned, the content that is returned is the Google SignOn page instead of the RSS.

Comment: You can try yourself, the code is very simple - that's all you need...

Comment: This request returns Google Sign-In page html content instead of RSS. This means that validation for some reason is not working for that RSS url. This is strange. Any suggestion how I can authenticate the request to consume the RSS is highly appreciated. Thanks a lot.